# CORS headers not set on PHP

Tags: php, ajax, curl, cors

Im trying to allow CORS on a PHP server
I have the following code

```
<?php 
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
echo '<p>Hello World!!</p>';
?>
```

and a simple ajax request to fetch it using jquery

I keep getting this CORS error on my dev tools

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I also used curl -i to check the response and im seeing it doesnt have the headers...
what is wrong

curl -i

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 31 Aug 2015 17:25:33 GMT
>   Content-Type:
>   text/html
>   Content-Length: 97
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Keep-Alive: timeout=30
>   Server: Apache/2
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
>   Cache-Control:
>   private, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0
>   Expires: 0
>   Pragma:
>   no-cache

Comment: @PaulCrovella i dont have * on the allow-headers , only on the Allow-origin which is ok , its not a duplicate

Comment: Check if the web server removes the header.

Comment: can you elaborate , im pretty sure it is

Comment: all of your headers are being ignored. note the content-type as well. Make **SURE** you haven't a "headers already sent" error situation.

Answer (score 0):

What  Charlotte Dunois commented gave the direction
i added the following line in my .htaccess file

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: Additionally it is important to understand that if PHP is not handling the OPTIONS request from the browser, the browser will not see the headers you set in PHP. So, like you discovered in your answer, you either need to set the headers at the server level or tell apache to pass HTTP OPTIONS method requests to PHP and handle it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the issue was the requested resource resided in a directory that had directory privacy applied to it by way of the .htaccess file residing in said directory. Removing the directory privacy allowed the php header to function as expected.